# retrieving data from rackspace database through python

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I have very little knowledge of rackspace..My client has setup one server at rackspace cloud and saying that he created one database and I have to retrieve data from there , while logging into https://mycloud.rackspace.com/ , I found that server is created at

PublicNet (Internet)  166.78.105.176

and I also can access database via phpmyadmin http://"link"/phpmyadmin

But the problem is I need instance Id of that database from cloud control panel to connect to database as said in http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/connecting-to-your-cloud-database , which I am not able to get as I am not able to see database in cloud control panel..

Please help..am I in right direction ? or I am totally in wrong path.

Any suggestions would be helpful me..

Comment: Hi Pawan, when you sign in to the Rackspace Cloud Control Panel and click on the "Databases" link at the top, do you see any database instances? Please make sure "All Regions (Global)" is selected in the pulldown menu on the left.

Comment: Hi Shaunak , That's the point..I dont see any database instances out there..do you know any other way it would have been accessed?

Comment: Hi Pawan, if you don't see a database instance in the Rackspace Control Panel then it is not a Rackspace Cloud Database you are accessing. My guess is the database is hosted locally on the same server (166.78.105.176).

Would you mind emailing us (sdk-support [at] rackspace.com) with your Rackspace username and we can try and help out.